# Create matrix with n elements from an array

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

Is there a way to create matrix that is consisted of a certain numbers that are stored in an array? For example, I want to create a 10-by-1 matrix consisting only of numbers from an array `a = [6,2,15,24]`, that are randomly stored in matrix elements. The final product should look something like this:

```
M = [15,24,2,15,2,6,24,15,2,15]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function b = resample( a, size )
indices = randi( numel( a ), size );
b = a( indices );
```

Example:

```
>> resample( [6,2,15,24],  [4,5] )
ans =

     2     6    15     2     6
     2     2    15    15     6
    24     6     6     2     6
     2     6    24     6     2
```

Comment: after a few runs of a code, it was shown that this is a better solution for my certain problem, so thank you very much @jez

Answer (score 3):

If you have the Statistics toolbox, you can use [`randsample`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/randsample.html) with the third argument set to `true` to indicate that the data `a` is to be sampled [*with* replacement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_(statistics)):

```
a = [6 2 15 24];
M = randsample(a,10,true)
```

Comment: thank you @horchler, this helps, i tried something with randsample before but didn't know about this true part and it didn't work, could you tell me what is the function of that true part so that i know for future?